# Can't find RequireSignedAppinit_DLLs in Registery

Tags: c++, windows, dll, dll-injection

I am trying to do a small dll injection on my computer, and it doesn't seem to work.
I updated `AppInit_DLLs` with the path to my dll, and I read online that I need to set `LoadAppinit_DLLs` to 1 (which I have) and `RequireSignedAppinit_DLLs` to 0 for the injection to work.

but I can't find `RequireSignedAppinit_DLLs` in the registery..

[My Registery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omEot.png)

And here is my dll code: (It's very messy I am just trying to see if it will work before I actually make it clean)

```
#include "pch.h"
#define DLL_EXPORT
#include "mydll.h"
extern "C"
{
    DECLDIR void Share()
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR)L"DLL injection!", (LPCWSTR)L"Hacked", 0);
    }
    void Keep()
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR)L"DLL injection!", (LPCWSTR)L"Hacked", 0);
    }
    DECLDIR void openWindow()
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR)L"DLL injection!", (LPCWSTR)L"Hacked", 0);
    }
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule, // Handle to DLL module

    DWORD ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved) // Reserved

{
    openWindow();
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        // A process is loading the DLL.
        Keep();
        Share();
        openWindow();
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        // A process is creating a new thread.
        Keep();
        Share();
        openWindow();
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        // A thread exits normally.
        Keep();
        Share();
        openWindow();
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        // A process unloads the DLL.
        Keep();
        Share();
        openWindow();
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Hope anyone can help...

Answer (score 0):

Just create the `RequireSignedAppinit_DLLs` REG_WORD value yourself.

This is fine for experimentation but a real application should not modify these values because it decreases the security of the system.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. ehhh it still doesn't work :( maybe there is a problem with my dll code? When I run a different visual studio project that imports the dll it works, but when I open something like Word or Excel it doesn't run the dll like it should.

Comment: If you are using Windows 8 or later you need to turn off UEFI secure boot as well. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/secure-boot-and-appinit-dlls

Comment: I am not using UEFI. I am using Legacy boot (whatever that means)...

Comment: Try Process Monitor. Does WINVER.exe load your dll?